# Variable contains same values (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

To generate a mailing list, I've recognized that in my variable "To" is containing the same values `test@test.com`. The mailing list was defined in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA). Well, I'm considering how could I define a statement to check, when the variable has the same values then trim all duplicates. That means I need the variable to appear just one time in the mailing list.

For example:

```
Dim objMail As Object
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objMail
  .To = test@test.com; name1@test.com; name2@test.com; name3@test.com; test@test.com; name4@test.com
  ...
End With
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: what data type is the "To" variable?  Is it an array?  Or a concatenated string?

Comment: Dump the list in to a dictionary. It's literally made for this sort of thing.

Comment: @StormsEdge I've edited my post. Now you can see the how the variable was defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the dictionary to remove the duplicates:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim EmailAddresses As String

    EmailAddresses = "test@test.com; name1@test.com; name2@test.com; name3@test.com; test@test.com; name4@test.com"
    EmailAddresses = RemoveDuplicates(EmailAddresses)

    Debug.Print EmailAddresses

End Sub

Public Function RemoveDuplicates(sTo As String) As String

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim vEmails As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim sTemp As String

    vEmails = Split(Replace(sTo, " ", ""), ";")
    If UBound(vEmails) > 0 Then
        'Remove duplicates.
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For x = LBound(vEmails) To UBound(vEmails)
            If Not dict.exists(vEmails(x)) Then
                dict.Add vEmails(x), 1
                sTemp = sTemp & vEmails(x) & ";"
            End If
        Next x
        sTemp = Left(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 1) 'Remove the final ;
        RemoveDuplicates = sTemp
    Else
        'There's only 1 address.
        RemoveDuplicates = sTo
    End If

End Function
```

The above can actually be simplified a few ways, too, if that's your preference.

1. For simple de-duping like this, no need to use the .`Exists` method or the `.Add` method because dictionary items are created lazily. This means that so simply referencing an item will create it if it doesn't exist, or overwrite it if it does.
2. Rather than manually constructing the string in parallel with the dictionary, you can `Join` function on the the dict's `Keys`.

Here's the revised version:

```
Public Function RemoveDuplicates2(sTo As String) As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim vEmails As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    vEmails = Split(Replace(sTo, " ", ""), ";")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For x = LBound(vEmails) To UBound(vEmails)
       dict(vEmails(x)) = dict(vEmails(x)) 'Keep track of how many occurrences, in case you want to do something with it later
    Next

    RemoveDuplicates = Join(dict.Keys(), "; ")

End Function
```

Comment: Good use of dictionary; I added a slightly simplified approach (& explanation) to your answer, hope that's OK :)

Comment: Yep, that's fine thanks @David.  I've only just started using the dictionary myself, so still getting my head around how it all works.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thanks Darren for your post. Could I combine your example with the variable, what I've added to my post additionally?